# While loop not running indefinitely [python3]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, command-line-interface

I'm creating TUI (Text-based user interface) using print statements, and when I want to return to the 'homescreen' i want the older code to run again.

```
randbool = True

while randbool:
    print('1')
    randbool = False

while not randbool:
    print('2')
    randbool = True
```

the result im expecting is

```
1
2
1
2
1
2
....
```

but it only prints 1, 2 how can I make it run indefinitely?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Just 1/2/1/2 indefinitely?

Comment: You have 1 while loop, which will run once then exit.  Then you have another while loop, which will run once then exit.  There is nothing in your code that will cause the execution to return to the first loop

Comment: @StevenMoseley Nah I just want to change loops, so that I can the same code twice

Comment: @ErenUcar be more specific. What do you want the program to do. What you're asking for is very ambiguous.

Comment: @StevenMoseley Doesn't matte anymore i just but the other while loop inside the existing one, all i wanted to was return to the first while loop after completing the second one

Answer (score 2):

Not advisable, but:

```
while True:
    print('1')
    print('2')
```

This will print 1,2,1,2,1,2 indefinitely, until your CPU usage is at 100%, and your whole system freezes.

But it will accomplish what you're asking for.

**Edit to add:** 100% CPU usage demonstrated on an i7 laptop with 16GB RAM on Ubuntu 18.04:

[image: 100% CPU]

Comment: Unless you have a *really* old computer, there is no way this would drive CPU usage to 100%.

Comment: @ScottHunter rather than arguing that fact with you, I pasted a screenshot above of the exact script running on my brand new i7 laptop.

Answer (score 1):

If the value of `randbool` lets you get in a loop, *changing* it will stop the loop.

So don't change it for a loop you don't want to stop.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print `1` and `2` indefinitely, a simpler solution would be:

```
# loop forever
while True:
    print('1')
    print('2')
```